# Use induction to show that a polynomial with $k$ terms has $k$ solutions.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, induction, rolles-theorem

First Part of the problem: Let $n_1 < . . . < n_k$ be non-negative integers, let $a_1, . . . , a_k$ be positive real numbers and let $f(x) = a_1x^
{n_1} + · · · + a_kx^{n_k}$ . Suppose $0 < s < t$ and $f(s) = f(t) = 0$. Show that the polynomial

$g(x) = a_1 + a_2x^{n_2−n_1} + · · · + a_kx^{n_k−n_1} = \frac{1}{x^{n_1}}f(x)$

satisfies $g'(x) = 0$ for some $x$ between $s$ and $t$. (Hint: Use Rolle’s Theorem).

My proof: We know that polynomials are continuous and differentiable, $\therefore$ we use Rolle's Theorem, since $f(s) = f(t)$, $\exists c \in (s,t)$ with $f'(c) = 0$.

Now we take the derivative of $g(x)$ using the product rule:

$g'(x) = (\frac{1}{x^n})'f(x) + (\frac{1}{x^n})f'(x)=$

$-\frac{n}{x^{-(1+n_1)}} + (\frac{1}{x^n})f'(x)$

From Rolle's theorem we know there is an x $\in (s,t)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$ and if $n_1=0$ then $g'(x) = 0$ for that same $x$.

Second Part of the problem:  Use induction on $k$ and Question 7 to show that the polynomial

$f(x) = a_1x^{n_1} + · · · + a_kx^{n_k}$

has at most $k$ positive solutions to $f(x) = 0$.

My attempt: Quite honestly I'm not sure how to start. I know I can use the base case $k = 1$ (and there is only one solution to that: $x = 0$), so I can assume for $k$ terms there are $k$ solutions. But I don't know where to go from there. Do I just keep taking derivatives and prove $k-1$? How can I use induction to prove $k+1$?

Comment: Between any two positive roots there is a root of the derivative. If $a_1x^{n_1}+...+a_{k+1}x^{n_{k+1}}$ has more than $k+1$ positive roots, then $(n_2-n_1)a_2x^{n_2-n_1-1}+...+(n_{k-1}-n_k)a_{k+1}x^{n_{k+1}-n_1-1}$ has more than $k$ positive solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is everywhere continuous, it suffices to note $g(s)=g(t)=0$.

Comment: So we can say that there $k-1$ solutions in $g'(x)$, because when you take the derivative of $g$, $a_1 = 0$? Would that suffice to show proof by induction?

Comment: @MehakWahla No. $a_1=0$ tells you that $x=0$ is a solution, but we are counting positive solutions, so the root at $x=0$ is irrelevant. What is important is that $g'$ has the same form as $f$ but with fewer terms. As I mentioned in the comment to the question, when $f$ has more positive roots than terms, that will force the derivative to also have many positive roots, contradicting the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you, I understand!